# Certain site URLs don't load

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, heroku, dns

So I have this website, lets call it `http://www.blah.com`.

It uses backbone.js as a framework, and is a single page application.

The domain is registered with domain.com and uses the very common vDeck control panel.

I have a stealth pointer to `www.blah.com` so that both `blah.com` and `www.blah.com` are available. (I think this is the problem area.)

I have a DNS CNAME Alias to `blah.herokuapp.com`, which is where the site is hosted.

For the user it looks like `www.blah.com/home`, or `www.blah.com/users`.

My problem is that even though `www.blah.com/home` and `blah.com` load fine, `blah.com/home` returns a Page Not Found Error from http://notfound01.domainparkingserver.net/?

Thanks

Comment: A CNAME for an apex record is against the DNS regulations - its amazing that what you have even works.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku says that some [DNS hosts provide a way to get CNAME-like functionality at the zone apex using a custom record type](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#root-domain); as @choco-loo’s comment says, CNAME isn’t technically supported at the `blah.com` level. If your provider supports any of those CNAME-like records for apex domains, try that?

Comment: blah.com no longer loads if I remove the stealth pointer and configure the CNAME as you said.

Comment: I updated the answer to link to Heroku’s suggestion on how to deal with this.